# Remove synonym [mvc] -> [model-view-controller] and add [mvc] -> [asp.net-mvc]

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, synonym-request

Currently, [mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mvc) is a synonym for [model-view-controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/model-view-controller). Understandable, but almost every other question about ASP.NET MVC is now getting the [model-view-controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/model-view-controller) tag, even though most of the questions have little to nothing to do with the pattern (which is ostensibly what [model-view-controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/model-view-controller) is for). I change them every time I see them, but that's quite often, and I'm getting the carpal-tunnel syndrome over here...

My proposal:

- Remove the [mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mvc) -> [model-view-controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/model-view-controller) synonym
- Add a [mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mvc) -> [asp.net-mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc) synonym

I would be amenable to removing/blacklisting [mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mvc) altogether, as I don't see it being a particularly useful tag.

Note: I am not saying that MVC and ASP.NET MVC are the same thing. They are obviously not the same thing. I am saying that the majority of people using [mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mvc) to tag their questions are using it to refer to ASP.NET MVC. My proposal is to face the reality of the situation and help those users rather than keeping the existing synonym around to be constantly misused.

Comment: there are a lot of MVC questions that have nothing at all to do with asp.net

Answer (score 6):

Your request is based on the flawed assumption that MVC and ASP.NET MVC are the same thing.<sup>*</sup> That's just not true. See, for example, [this blog post](http://blog.iandavis.com/2008/12/what-are-the-benefits-of-mvc/), explaining that MVC as a concept originated in 1988, long before ASP.NET:

> The Model/View/Controller (MVC) triad of classes [first described by [Krasner and Pope](http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=50757.50759) in 1988] is used to build user interfaces in Smalltalk-80. Looking at the design patterns inside MVC should help you see what we mean by the term "pattern." MVC consists of three kinds of objects. The Model is the application object, the View is its screen presentation, and the Controller defines the way the user interface reacts to user input. Before MVC, user interface designs tended to lump these objects together. MVC decouples them to increase flexibility and reuse.

"MVC" has meanings other than "ASP.NET MVC." It would be incorrect and confusing to make [mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mvc) a synonym for [asp.net-mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc). Blacklisting it entirely would be even more incorrect.

---

<sup>*</sup> You edited your question to clarify that you are not saying the concepts are the same. But now, your question rests on a different assumption: that we should name and use tags here based on how people use or misuse them, rather than based on what they mean. That's also an incorrect assumption. Stack Overflow is what you might call a highly-opinionated system with respect to proper naming of things. It's prescriptive, not descriptive.

If a user wants to tag a post as being about MVC, but not about ASP.NET MVC, we should let them, as long as it's an on-topic post. Making it impossible for people to do that would violate user expectations and, ultimately, make the site less useful.

Comment: It would not be impossible for people to tag a post about the model view controller pattern, as the `model-view-controller` tag would continue to exist.

Comment: Just get one of those internet-enabled hammers and when someone tags an asp.net-mvc post with mvc simply hit them on the fingers.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan That just makes the confusion even worse. "MVC no longer means the same as 'model-view-controller?' What the...?"

Comment: Okay. Just trying to inject some pragmatism into the process, but considering most people are loathe to even spell "I'm" as anything other than "im", I guess I won't run out of other edits to do while I'm editing ASP.NET MVC questions.