# Did Kermit get his box of paperclips?

Tags: discussion, support, statistics, tag-tips

3.5 years ago it was suggested to show a popup for certain tags that would help inexperienced users understand how to best form their question for said tag:
[Help the helpless with how-to-ask tag tips](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274632/help-the-helpless-with-how-to-ask-tag-tips)

One such popup [was implemented](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274634/1843331) for [sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql):
[image]

This will show when you add the sql tag to a question. Other tags (such as [[latex]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303245/suggest-posting-to-tex-when-tagging-question-with-latex-etc)) have this as well.

In the following years, multiple comments asked for the results of this experiment, but none got a response, which leaves us all wondering if [Kermit ever got his box of paperclips](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274632/help-the-helpless-with-how-to-ask-tag-tips/274634#comment106688_274634).

I am interested in some results:

- Did it improve this specific tag usage?
- Did it increase the quality of questions in this tag?
- Was it useful (or not) in other ways?

---

The reason I'm asking is I'm quite active in the [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) tag, and the majority of the android questions that are also tagged [android-studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-studio) are wrongfully tagged so and have in fact absolutely nothing to do with the IDE. I retag some questions every day, but as you are aware there is a never-ending flood of new questions, and it is quite demoralizing to see *yet another* misuse of [android-studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-studio).

[I discussed the issue with some members of SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/conversation/tag-popup-request) and they pointed out that similar issues have occurred in the past, and the mentioned help popups might be able to improve the situation. However before requesting a help popup for [android-studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-studio), it would be important to know if previously implemented help popups had a positive effect.

---

<sub>[Kermit's paperclips reference](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274632/help-the-helpless-with-how-to-ask-tag-tips/274634#comment106688_274634)</sub>

Comment: Not so sure you are going to like the answer to this question.  It is pretty irrelevant, [sql] falls in the [regex] lost-cause-tag category and has nothing to do with [android] tags.  If you want a similar popup from Shog9 for [android-studio] questions then the best way to get one is to propose the popup text.

Comment: @HansPassant that was indeed my goal, however I was advised to inform about these results before I go and post a request for a popup for a different tag

Comment: The person that can do this is the same person that has the statistics.  Mere mortals like us don't have access to accurate data, deleted questions cannot be queried.  Re-iterating, you are not going to get a popup if you don't tell him what you want to see inside of it.

Comment: I understand the request, but common mistaggings are not really limited to android + android-studio. Tagging the tools used in a project even when the question is absolutely not about those tools just seems to happen a lot.

Comment: @Gimby eclipse, xcode, shell, bash...

Comment: @Gimby you are right, of course. But regardless of the scope, I think if we are going to make an effort to try to improve the situation, we should start by checking the results of previous (or rather, the current) efforts. If they prove ineffective, we at least know this is not how we should proceed

Comment: [This is also implemented for tag:latex](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303245/suggest-posting-to-tex-when-tagging-question-with-latex-etc), which can probably be checked rather easily: if there are less migrations since the pop-up was put in place, apparently it works.

Comment: This could be implemented as an additional bit of text in the tag info area. Then the community could maintain them instead of bugging Shog9 every time (assuming of course that they make a difference, which I admit is a big assumption, but I can only make assumptions until this question is answered).

Comment: @Mike ideally, yes. But I feel that people who use the wrong tags do not usually care to read said tag info/description. The AndroidStudio tag for example explicitly says not to use it for general android questions, yet it is happens on a massive scale

Comment: Right, I was thinking that the text which shows in the popup (e.g., what's showing in the SQL popup in the image) would be editable by the community. Not as part of the excerpt/wiki, but rather as a third box in the tag info page (with a preview clearly indicating it's for the popup). I agree that people don't read tag excerpts; it led me to [ask my least popular question on Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/338110/215552) :).

Comment: @Mike ah. In that case, sounds good to me :-) (unless kermit did not get his paperclips of course)

Comment: Is there a correlation between mistagging and low-rep? The mistaggers are probably just trying to increase visibility of their question. In that case the popup is unlikely to help with tagging.

Comment: @AaronCicali from what I've seen, there is at least some correlation between experience in a tag, and misusing the associated tags. I regularly see questions like "how do I split a string in Android studio?"- where OP does not seem to know it has nothing to do with the IDE, and thinks that it is important information to add. I'm also not sure low rep users are even aware that more tags means more visibility. Perhaps Shog has some numbers to shed light on the matter

Comment: AFAIK, there was a query that indicated that questions with 5 tags get less attention than those with 2 or 3 tags. Of course, that may have something to do with the quality of the tags used.