# Do "answers" to discussion "questions" on meta have to be "answers"?

Tags: discussion, answers, meta

AFAICT Meta is for discussion not just Q&A

Example: Here is a discussion "thread"

[I'm resigning as a Stack Overflow community elected moderator](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/390427/im-resigning-as-a-stack-overflow-community-elected-moderator)

It is not even asking a question. There are 31 "answers" which are not an answer to any question.

[Here is another non-question with non-answers discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252506/question-quality-is-dropping-on-stack-overflow)

[And another](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/386324/the-stack-overflow-i-wish-to-build-and-participate-in-is-no-longer-supported?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[Here's question but the answers are not answers they are discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366665/does-stack-exchange-really-want-to-conflate-newbies-with-women-people-of-color)

And yet, recently one of my responses to a discussion was deleted as "not an answer" though it was fully on topic to the discussion being had.

Are meta discussion threads for discussing things or does someone need to delete the threads above as "not a question" and all the responses as "not an answer"?

Comment: That question should not have been tagged with [discussion], the OP needed a concrete answer instead of a bunch of opinions.  Fixed.

Comment: Without knowing what question you posted an answer to, and the contents of that answer, we can't speak to your specific case.

Comment: Perhaps you could delete to your answer that got deleted, and maybe a +10k could tell you why?

Answer (score 6):

> Do “answers” to discussion “questions” on meta have to be “answers”?

Yes, it is still a "question and answer" site.

> Are meta discussion threads for discussing things or does someone need to delete the threads above as "not a question" and all the responses as "not an answer"?

No, nobody needs to delete the Q&A you linked.

Meta is slightly different from main in some ways. For example, it can be used for announcements; either from the company or from the moderator team; and in those cases no clear "question" is posed.

What makes those "questions" work differently is not that they are tagged [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion), but the inherent nature of certain topics allowed in Meta.

And even then, the "answers" have to be posted as a clear response to the original post.

Comment: There are 1000s of other examples of "answers" that are not actual answers but are just discussion of the topic listed in the "question".

Comment: Is there a guideline for what's on-topic on meta?

Comment: [What is "meta"? How does it work?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta)

Comment: Thank you. But I meant a more in-dept guideline, that for instance also explains if a post need to ask a Question, and if in any circumstance it doesn't. The "gray areas".

Comment: @Scratte If it was written down, it wouldn't be a gray area :).

Comment: @HereticMonkey I see your point, but that's another gray area. A post that heavily discusses what can/cannot be posted would be "written down". It could also reveal gray areas with possible opinionated arguments.Those posts usually link to examples. I have been wanting to post something on meta for a while, but I'm highly confused as to it's on-topic-ness. I'd much rather spend a few hours reading posts to educate myself first, but I've not found any relevant posts about it, and I had hoped a seasoned user would be much better finding those.

Comment: @Scratte I'd search the [meta-tag:faq] tag. But honestly, just post whatever it is. It's not like your rep is affected. I've got [a -11 question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/338110/215552) (granted, on-topic, but definitely not popular) that I'm none too proud of, and some other long-timers have posts which are downvoted or closed as off-topic. Meta is where there is just a lot of gray, and keeping it that way makes it easier to discuss the things that need discussing sometimes, IMO.

Comment: This answer seems to be providing conflicting advice. First it says "yes", but then it follows up with a long-worded "no" for the rest of the post.

Comment: @TylerH The question ask two questions. "Yes" is the answer to the title. "No" is the answer to "should we delete..." at the end. Maybe I'll add some quotations to make it clearer.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit of a grey zone, I guess. You may have just been unlucky.

Meta relaxes the rules on the main site to some (limited) extent. Discussion is an important part of the Meta activity. While answers to questions without the discussion tag should be strictly on-topic, answers to discussion-tagged questions can digress a bit more. How much more is difficult to estimate. Consequently, flagging could be inconsistent there and different people will have different notions there. If you disagree, you could ask about a specific action on meta.

As for the questions posed: There is always an implicit question included even for announcements and that is: "What do you think about this?". Maybe it should be made more explicit.

From experience I would say that the leeway is even larger for moderator or community manager resignation-Q&As. Their status is very special and does not allow generalizing to all other questions on Meta. Except for the last months, they do not occur often though.