# How are the placeholder tags selected for a question?

Tags: support, tags, asking-questions, user-interface

I was posting a question at Stack Overflow.

The placeholder (`placeholder="e.g. (asp.net-mvc angularjs jquery)"`) for tags seemed a bit outdated to me.

[image]

How are they selected?

Comment: Are those context-dependent or not? They are all web development related. Would they be different for, e.g., an embedded software development related question? What are some previous meta questions about placeholders?

Comment: They are not context-dependent. The only way the system can tell what type of question you're asking (e.g., web, embedded, etc.) is based on the *tags*, and once you fill in the tags, there is no need for (and even no way to show) placeholders. @PeterMortensen

Comment: If we could modify it slightly to "asp.net-mvc NOT mvc (model-view-controller)", [I for one would be happier](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/338110/215552) :).

Comment: A little background, I develop predominately in Microsoft stack. Used a lot of jquery and angularjs. Its not my lack of familiarity with them. To me angularjs and jquery are outdated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The system randomly picks three of the top 50 tags to display based on the number of questions with that tag all-time, so it's somewhat expected that the tags may be somewhat long-standing topics rather than newer ones. The selected tags are cached for 24 hours so they change every day or so. The tags don't change immediately upon the cache expiration, someone has to load the ask question page first. As such, you'll see that all three of those tags are either on [the first page of the tags list](https://stackoverflow.com/tags) or the [first few rows of the second page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags?page=2&tab=popular).

Since asking the question, the tags have updated, so you can confirm for yourself that they do change.

The system doesn't parse what you're asking about because the content is created before you start typing.

Comment: @Catija According to the code, the cache expiration for that value is 60 * 60 * 24 (or one day). It also looks at the top 50 tags on Stack Overflow, and only the top 30 on other sites. :) This doesn't run on a scheduled task, though. Not all sites will update at the same time. Just whenever the cache expires, it will select new tags the next time someone opens the ask page.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know that. And yes now I get `python css excel`. There wont be a question if I had seen that tags :)

Comment: "or the first **few** rows of the second page." => 4x9=36 Tags displayed on the 1st Page / per Page (what an odd Number btw...!), => +14 = 4x3=12 +2 => "or the first **4** rows of the second page."